# Conditional folder redirect on windows

Tags: windows, filesystems, folder-redirection

I'm trying to find a way to conditionally redirect a path based on process location.

The rule would be something like this:

```
if process path begins with "U:\apps_to_redirect\" then
  "c:\users\me\documents" redirects to "c:\users\me\redirected_files"
else
  "c:\users\me\documents" doesn't redirect
```

In short I want all applications to be able to access the files on "c:\users\me\documents" normally with the exception of any application in "u:\apps_to_redirect" which instead sees a different folder.

I've looked into using the [CorrectFilePaths](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766201(v=ws.10).aspx) compatibility shim, but it seems to be designed to apply to a single application and not a folder source path. I also looked into [Reparse Points](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365503(v=vs.85).aspx) but it wasn't clear how to make a conditional one.

So I'm asking here in the hopes someone knows some better/straightforward way of doing this on Windows 10.